# textFieldShouldBeginEditing is called after unwind segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, unwind-segue

I have 2 view controllers.

If the text field from first view controller is clicked, it takes the user to second view controller.

Second view controller has table view and when the selection is made, it takes the user back to first view controller using unwind segue.

**First View Controller**

```
- (IBAction)unwindFromModalViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([segue.sourceViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
    {
        SecondViewController *secondVC = segue.sourceViewController;
        if (secondVC.selectedData)
        {
            self.textField.text = secondVC.selectedData;
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.textField)
    {
        SecondViewController *secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

**Second View Controller**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *selectedRow = [self.json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.selectedData = [selectedRow objectForKey:@"data"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tofirstVC" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]])
    {
        FirstViewController *firstVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        if (self.selectedData)
        {
            firstVC.textField.text = self.selectedData;
        }
    }
}
```

After the user comes back to the first view controller, textFieldShouldBeginEditing is called and it takes the user back to the second view controller.

What is causing this, and how can I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried resignFirstResponder, but still not working. I also tried endEditing but no luck :(

Comment: I am trying to navigate users to the second view that has table view, and when selection is made users come back to the first view and the textfield's text is set to the selection

Comment: Just found adding `self.textField.enabled = NO` stops the issue, but can't click the textfield to call second view controller

Comment: I already did, but no luck

Comment: in textFieldShouldBeginEditing have you tried resignFirstResponder?

Comment: Then try with tapgesture on UITextField

Comment: I don't think that is the problem

Comment: Try some flag for checking in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, if the input came from second VC: `if (! fromSecondVC) { // process to second VC ... }`. Set this flag in second VC before unwinding

Comment: @schmidt9 what if the user wants to go back to the second view controller?

Comment: You can eg. use gesture recognizer to catch tap on you text field an to unset the flag

Answer (score 0):

I made an example. Note, that when we set text to text view in delegate method, `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is not being called, as we want. In storyboard push segue id "toSecondVC" must be set. By the way I don't understand why you use here `UITextField`, because you can't edit the text manually anyway.

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, SecondViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    _textField.text = text;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.textField)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSecondVC" sender:self];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSecondVC"]) {
        SecondViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.delegate = self;
    }
}

@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)setText:(NSString*)text;

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedData;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()
{
    NSArray *_data;
}

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _data = @[@"first", @"second", @"third"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _data.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = _data[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.selectedData = _data[indexPath.row];
    [_delegate setText:_selectedData];
    if ([_delegate isMemberOfClass:[FirstViewController class]]) {
        [(FirstViewController*)_delegate dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. The issue was with textFieldShouldBeginEditing returning YES, which keeps the loop.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.textField)
    {
        SecondViewController *secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

After removing `return YES;` it resolved the issue.

Comment: May I know, why do you use text field here and not let's say a label or a button, since we cannot edit text?

Comment: Just for looks. Is there a reason not to use text fields?

Comment: Well if you are not going to edit text, then you could use another non-editable control and avoid these workarounds with `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`

Comment: Hmm... Like which one? I dont like the label

Comment: `UIButton` for instance

Comment: I guess that can be an option too